# Segmentation Fault accessing qpscale_table in AVFrame

Tags: c++11, h.264, libavcodec

I'm modifying this file slightly: https://gist.github.com/yohhoy/f0444d3fc47f2bb2d0e2
This code decodes a video and makes opencv Mats out of the frame pixels as it goes.

In particular I only want to grab frames that have specific macroblock-related data. I'm attempting to get that data like this:

`total_qp = get_total_qp(decframe->qscale_table, mb_width, mb_height, mb_stride);`

However, whenever I try to access the data by iterating over that array, I get a segmentation fault:

```
static float get_total_qp(int8_t *qscale_table, int mb_width, int mb_height, int mb_stride)
{
    int mb_count = mb_height * mb_width;
    int y, x;
    float qp_total = 0.0f;
    for (y = 0; y < mb_height; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < mb_width; x++) {
            qp_total += qscale_table[x + y * mb_stride]; <-- SEGFAULT here
        }
    }
    return qp_total;
}
```

I've also tried sending in:
`frame->qscale_table`

and I've tried populating it, but this own't compile because it can't find that function:

```
int8_t *qscale_table = av_frame_get_qp_table(decframe->qscale_table, &mb_stride, &qscale_type);
```

So my question is this:
Given an `AVFrame*` how do I ensure that the `qscale_table` is populated and access it?

Comment: Almost 100% chance that `x + y * mb_stride` is reading past the end of your array.  You should look at this in a debugger and verify.  The other possibility is that `qscale_table` is garbage or NULL.  Asserts can catch that.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan printing data shows (I think) that qscale_table is indeed NULL. Hence my question - how do I get it populated? I thought it got populated as part of the decoding process - at least, it does with ffmpeg, which is why you can debug out the QP values. So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the qpscale_table doesn't get exported onto the decoded frame after the decoding happens in h264dec.c.

In order to retrieve the values I had to modify the `finalize_frame` method in `h264dec` to export the qscale_table onto the frame, like so:

```
static int h264_export_qp_table(H264Context *h, AVFrame *f, H264Picture *p, int qp_type)
{
    AVBufferRef *ref = av_buffer_ref(p->qscale_table_buf);
    int offset = 2*h->mb_stride + 1;
    if(!ref)
        return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
    av_assert0(ref->size >= offset + h->mb_stride * ((f->height+15)/16));
    ref->size -= offset;
    ref->data += offset;
    return av_frame_set_qp_table(f, ref, h->mb_stride, f->qscale_type);
}
```

and add in the call into `finalize_frame`:

```
...
        if (CONFIG_MPEGVIDEO) {
            ff_print_debug_info2(h->avctx, dst, NULL,
                                 out->mb_type,
                                 out->qscale_table,
                                 out->motion_val,
                                 NULL,
                                 h->mb_width, h->mb_height, h->mb_stride, 1);
            // NT: make the qscale_table accessible!
            h264_export_qp_table(h, dst, out, FF_QSCALE_TYPE_H264);
        }
...
```

And then recompile FFmpeg using these instructions: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu